# sqldf missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, sqldf

In sqldf_0.4-7.1 I get:

```
 Error in if (.allows_extensions(db)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Where is the package that fixes the bug? My error is the same as the one generated by:

```
sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 6")
```

I downloaded sqldf v0.4-7.1 from CRAN but with newer source does not help some 8 hours later.

Comment: Please provide your query

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with that sqldf version.  Fixed version should be already on the cran so you will need to update your sqldf package.

Download file [sqldf_0.4-9.tar.gz](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sqldf_0.4-9.tar.gz) and in console run:

```
R CMD INSTALL sqldf_0.4-9.tar.gz
```

Comment: can't able to install the package through comment prompt in Windows,throwing me an error "INSTALL" is not recognized as internal and external command.